# Facebook: prevent webpages to auto-like themselves with my connected account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Recently, I've seen a lot of webpages (external to Facebook) that implement an auto-like script (google "facebook auto like" and you'll see how many of these things there are out there).

It works as follows: you are connected to your facebook account. On another tab (or window) you visit a "malicious" website, that has this script. You don't click on anything related to Facebook, especially nothing that asks for permission. When you go back to your Facebook account, you observe that your profile has liked the page you visited, without your permission.

Is there a way to prevent these script from working? Otherwise, is there a security parameter that would make Facebook to always ask for your password before liking anything outside Facebook? I would even be fine with disabling likes outside Facebook altogether.

Comment: Simply log out of Facebook after using it and before visiting other websites …

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I usually always have Facebook opened in a separate tab because I use it for chat. I don't want to change my habits because of the bad behaviors of some websites :)

Answer (score 0):

For the websites to accomplish auto liking, they need to use a web based programming language like Javascript, before you enter a website that you don't know, try turning off the JavaScript in tools until you can trust that site, a second option if you are using Google Chrome is to download an app that will block Javascript from running without your permission.

Comment: This would work, but I like having Javascript on by default (otherwise for every new website I visit I will have to activate it manually).